# Weird list output of __int64

Tags: c++, c, int64

im having a problem with `__int64` and `%I64u`. or may be there is a problem with my formula. i am trying to mimic the output below. but there is a weird thing happen in some line items. i cant understand what happened since others were printed fine.

NOTE: the main source of these list are from binary raw data. so i fetched it from hex and trying to convert it in `__int64`. my list consist of `120` line items which outputs well up to line `73` and fail from line `74` with expected value of `2276812558` and displayed `18446744071691396878`. From line `74` up to line `120` results are `intermittent`. others are ok and other lines fail.

anyone help??

SOURCE:

```
74  2276812558     <-- expected output
...
110 88343310421     <-- expected output
111 101677534814    <-- expected output
112 116372862414    
113 132547934111    <-- expected output
114 150330130721
115 169856101434    <-- expected output
116 193905458276    
117 220253625665    
118 249089120712    <-- expected output
119 280613529205    
120 315042247217
```

here is my code:

```
    longint =  (__int64)((col[3] << 24) | (col[2] << 16) | (col[1] << 8)) | ((col[0]) | (__int64)((col[7] << 56) | (col[6] << 48) | (col[5] << 40) | (col[4] << 32)) << 32);
sprintf(longintbuf,"%I64u", longint );
```

.OUTPUT GENERATED

```
74  18446744071691396878    <-- err
...
110 18446744071858548821    <-- err
111 18446744072307871326    <-- err
112 116372862414    
113 18446744073113499551    <-- err
114 150330130721    
115 18446744071766961210    <-- err
116 193905458276    
117 220253625665    
118 18446744073690569160    <-- err
119 280613529205    
120 315042247217
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `col` isn't an array of 64-bit types, your shifts are causing undefined behaviour.  Cast before shifting:

```
(__int64)col[7] << 56
```

It's also undefined behaviour if the shift would cause a sign change, so be careful for that when using signed types (like you are).

From C11 **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators** (emphasis mine):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. *If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.*
>
> The result of **`E1 << E2`** is **`E1`** left-shifted **`E2`** bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. ... *If **`E1`** has a signed type and nonnegative value, and **`E1` × 2<sup>E2</sup>** is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: i already casted it. the bitset displays fine. i tried two lines in (win) calculator. and it displays the correct value. in my case (in my codes case) it seems like there is something happen inside my compiler or maybe that was the undefined behaviour.

but why does calc computed it correctlly? pretty sure there is a way to correct it.

Comment: lets take a look with calc

`01111011 10111100 10111110 11110110`
this bit set displays `2075967222` in my calc and displays correct in my program. however 

`10000111 10110101 01100111 00001110` 
this bit set dislays CORRECT in my calc (with value of `2276812558`) but displayed `18446744071691396878` in my output. and this output has a bitset of `1100110011001100110011001100110001101100100100010001111100111`

Comment: There is a way to correct it - do the casting properly and check for signedness problems.  I'm not sure why you think something else is going on.

Comment: thanks Carl the casting really solves the problem. my sample post was processed the first 32bits and the 32nd bit was the antagonist. i casted each byte to `__int64`, applied those shifting and voila! problem solved. Again, many thanks!